# Allergies Dataset

Tags: data-request, food

I was wondering if there is a dataset that contains a user and the different (food) allergies the user has or doesn't have. So something like:

```
       Food1  Food2  Food3   ...
User1    0      1      0
User2    1      0      0 
User3    1      1      1 
...
```

I've looked at various datasets, but they all seem to represent a population, not an individual user.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: do you mean like real people? What's the use case?